# The name for a sentence that uses a word that can be a noun or a verb both ways: "We swing on the swing"

Tags: word-request, verbs, nouns

> We swing on the swing.
>   Glue( to use glue) with Glue.
>    Juice (to squeeze to make juice) to make juice.

What is the name for these kind of sentences that the noun and verb are the same?

Comment: It is called 'conversion'. Also known as 'zero derivation' or 'verbification'.

Comment: @user178049, I think the OP is asking about the name of *the sentences in which one word is used as a noun as well as verb*.

Comment: @decapitated I don't think there is a technical name for that. It is just a sentence.

Comment: There is no term for this type of sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether it's what you are looking for, but they are examples of *tautology* - saying the same thing twice in different ways - which is an error. If you refer to glueing something, it's superfluous to add 'with glue'; to juice something is, by definition, 'to obtain juice'.